# How to send signed data to backed and verify it?

Tags: ether, javascript, signature, timestamp

On a web page I have some 3 fields, name, age and height, which a user **authenticated via MetaMask** sends to backend **along** with **his wallet address**. In JSON.

In order to ensure that  data that's sent hasn't been tampered and his wallet address indeed belongs to him, I'll have to ask a user to sign data, right? I'm aware of how to do it:

```
 let mySigData = await this.mySigner.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify("some data"));
```

I'll also include a timestamp in data to prevent re-usage of a signature.

However, **what is it** what I actually will have to send from a client to then send to backend? What will all the data (data + payload) look like?

And how will I then deconstract it on a server properly?

Option #1

```
{
  name: "name1",
  age: 367,
  height: 188, 
  sig: "fdsafdsafdsafds$$2fds####",
  timestamp: 1236366
}
```

Option #2

```
{
  sig: "#6$$,,##$$-safd8543gfds", //name, age and height have somehow been embeded here 
  timestamp: 1236366
}
```

I'm aware how to verify a signature itself in `ether.js` but I mean the whole data itself.

On a server I'll then call .... what?

```
  const verify = ethers.utils.verifyMessage("???", params["sig"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, your data structure could be:

```js
let user = {
    data: {
        name: 'name1',
        age: 367,
        height: 188, 
        timestamp: 1236366,
    },
    address: '0x<UserAddress>',
    sig: '...'
}
```

#### Signing

To sign the `data` you must serialize it and the most simple serialization would be to use `JSON.stringify`

```typescript
let message = utils.arrayify(JSON.stringify(user.data);
user.address = await this.mySigner.getAddress();
user.sig = await this.mySigner.signMessage(message);
```

#### Recover Address

On the backend side, after receiving the user object, you should serialize the data in the same manner and recover the address with the signature:

```typescript
let message = utils.arrayify(JSON.stringify(params.data);
let address = utils.verifyMessage(message, params.sig);
```

Depending on your further logic you can check:

1. if `params.address` is equal to the recovered address
2. if the `address` is allowed to submit data
3. ...

---

The most important key point here, regardless of the data structure you choose, is that it depends on your business logic. The serialization of the data takes place on the front end for signing. Subsequently, the raw data along with the signature is sent to the backend. The backend serializes the data in the same way and verifies if it can be retrieved for the expected address using the provided signature.

Comment: **What** json data actually gets sent from the browser in an ajax request: `user` or `message`?

Comment: Shouldn't the `address` field been included into `data` sub-object instead?

Comment: You send raw data and the signature to the backend. On the frontend the data is serialized to the message and signed, on the backend the data is serialized in the same way to the message and recovered by using the signature.  And sure you can include the user `address` inside the `data` object.